# Is it a good choice to implement IoT Server using Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: performance

[image]

For Arduino (MQTT Client): Light Sensor, Light, etc.
For Raspberry Pi 3: Node.js server (with AngularJS front end), MQTT Broker, MongoDB

Will the Raspberry Pi 3 Overload? or use Raspberry Pi 3 as MQTT Broker only and use PC for Node.js server with MongoDB
Any other recommendation, I have 2xArduino Uno with Ethernet Shield, 1x Raspberry Pi 3 and 3x ESP8266 EP01

Comment: You are asking for comments on an architecture suitable to solve an unknown problem.  Not really a question for this site.

Comment: Without expected usage levels, messaging rates, number of users this is entirely hypothetical.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not; in fact this is kind of an ideal use case for it.  All the prerequisite software is available, and unless you expect hundreds or thousands of users on the LAN it should easily be able to juggle everything.

The thing I would look most closely at is MongoDB.  I have not used it much, but I seem to recall it can be a little greedy memory wise.  It is still hard to imagine whatever you have planned there as being so elaborate that this is a problem though.